# HTML element generated with javascript are not shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, astrojs

I'm trying to generate a "circle of fifth" with html/css/javascript
I'm just trying to reproduce this tutorial:
https://blog.logrocket.com/interactive-svg-circle-of-fifths/

I'm using the astro framework, but I don't think my issue come from this detail.
Nonetheless, I'm using 4 components:

- a Slice component, which contains the 3 black background portions of the slice and the 3 others components
- a TextInner Component, which is the text in the inner portion of the slice (the minor key)
- a TextMiddle component, which is the text in the middle portion of a slice (the major key)
- a Staff Component, which is the representation of a music staff, the outter portion of a slice

My problem is that I can't to properly display the sharps and flats on the staff dynamically.

If I do:

```html
<g id={staffId}>
  <use width="30" href="#staff"></use>
  <use width="2" href="#sharp" class="cf-sharp-1"></use>
  <use width="2" href="#sharp" class="cf-sharp-2"></use>
</g>
```

I get :

[image: The circle with the 2 sharps for every slice, as expected, but not correct]

With this code in the browser inspector

[image: the generated code]

But, if I comment the two "sharp" elements and try two generate them programatically with javascript, the html code generated seems correct, but the sharps are not displayed.
here is the code of the component:

```
---
import "../styles/global.css";

const { sliceIndex } = Astro.props;
const { alteration } = Astro.props;
const { alterationCount } = Astro.props;
const staffId = "staff-" + sliceIndex;
---

<g id={staffId}>
  <use width="30" href="#staff"></use>
  <!-- <use width="2" href="#sharp" class="cf-sharp-1"></use> -->
  <!-- <use width="2" href="#sharp" class="cf-sharp-2"></use> -->
</g>

<script define:vars={{ sliceIndex, alteration, alterationCount }}>
const size = 300; /* diameter / viewBox */
const radius = size / 2;
const angle = sliceIndex * (360 / 12);

function posXY(center, radius, angle) {
  return [
    center + radius * Math.cos((angle * Math.PI) / 180.0),
    center + radius * Math.sin((angle * Math.PI) / 180.0),
  ];
}

const [x, y] = posXY(radius, 125, angle);

const staffId = "staff-" + sliceIndex;
var staff = document.getElementById(staffId);
const xStaff = x - 15;
const yStaff = y - radius;
const translateStaff = "translate(" + xStaff + "," + yStaff + ")";

console.log(alterationCount);
console.log(alteration);
staff.setAttribute("transform", translateStaff);
for (let i = 1; i <= alterationCount; i++) {
  const alterationSymbol = document.createElement("use");
  alterationSymbol.setAttribute("width", 2);
  if (alteration == "sharp") {
    alterationSymbol.setAttribute("href", "#sharp");
    alterationSymbol.setAttribute("class", "cf-sharp-" + i);
  } else {
    alterationSymbol.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#flat");
    alterationSymbol.setAttribute("class", "cf-flat-" + i);
  }
  staff.appendChild(alterationSymbol);
}
</script>
```

Here is the generated code where we can see that the two sharps (for that slice) are correctly generated (the same html elements are generated):

[image]

But here is what is displayed:

[image]

None of the sharps/flats are displayed. I don't understand why, since the generated html elements in the inspector are the same.

Here's the full github project:
https://github.com/0inp/circleoffifth

Thanks a lot in advance for the help !

EDIT:
the SVG elements are already in my document as shown in this image:

[image: svg elements shown in the inspector]

That's why I'm using the `<use>` html tag.

Comment: I think those are SVG elements, not HTML elements.

Comment: Yep that's correct. The `<use>` tag is there to "copy" SVG element with the "href" attribute.
I don't understand really how the first version works, but it works, I can display the two "sharp" symbols with that `<use>` element.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092445/15261914 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62666066/15261914

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are trying to create SVG elements. Although SVG is allowed to be embedded directly into HTML, you should understand that it is not HTML, so when you use `document.createElement` you create HTML elements and of course SVG does not care about them. Use `document.createElementNS` to create a namespaced element. Everything you do related to SVG should always use `document.createElementNS` instead of `document.createElement`.

Comment: Ok I understand ! Thanks. 
So, how can I generate that sharp symbol with an svg element with javascript?

Comment: I edited the original post. I found that the svg elements are already generated. I don't want to generate them with js. 
That's explain why I can see the "sharp" symbol when I explicitly write the `<use>` tag in the html.
Now, I want to generate dynamically the `<use>` tag (this part seems okay in the inspector nonetheless) and see them in my browser

Comment: Same issue. `<use>` is an SVG tag, so you have to create an instance with a namespace for it to work.

Comment: Aaaahhhhh !!!
Thanks a lot !
Indeed, changing for
```const alterationSymbol = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use")
```
works like a charm !

Thanks everybody